# Problem on creating Firestore document using Firebase user ID

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

all.

I'm developing a web app using Vue.js + Firebase.
In the project, I'm developing a sign-up feature.

That feature basically uses an firebase auth function and it works correctly.
As an additional feature, I need to create a document in the Firestore 'users' collection. Here, the document ID is shall be same as the auth UID. But that doesn't work as intended.
I just need some help.

```js
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebase_config)
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebaseApp.auth();
export {db, auth};
```

```js
import {db,auth} from '../plugins/firebase'

// ( omit ) //

methods: {
  // this works
  test: function(){
    db.collection("users").doc("new_user").set({
      displayName: "Bob",
    }).catch(error=>{
      console.log('error on debugging: ',error)
    })
  },
    
  register: function(){
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.user_mail, this.user_password)
    .then(result=>{
      // this works
      console.log(result.user.uid)

      // this does not work
      db.collection('users').doc(result.user.uid).set({
        displayName: 'John',
      }).catch(error=>{
        console.log('fail to add data: ',error)
      })
    })
    .catch(error=>{
      console.log('something goes wrong on auth: ',error)
    })
  }
}
```

Firestore security rules are temporally as below.

```
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write, create: if request.auth.uid != null;
}
```

Comment: You are not checking for errors on the call to set().  It returns a promise that you should handle.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for your advice. I've changed my code as below, however, I couldn't add a document and I couldn't get error. ```        db.collection('users').doc(result.user.uid).set({
          displayName: 'John',
        }).catch(error=>{
          console.log('fail to add data: ',error)
        })```

Comment: Please edit the question to show your updated code that checks for errors as well as the error message itself.

Comment: What is `firebaseApp`? You define the Firebase Auth service with `firebase.auth()` and you define the Firestore service with `firebaseApp.firestore()`. You should most probably do `firebase.firestore()` since `firebase.auth()` seem to work.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've editted the question. I'm afraid that no error message occurs on the script.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec firebaseApp was the instance of firebase. I've fixed my script and added some scripts on the question. I think I have followed your advice, but if it's not as intended, please say so.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `AngularFire` library then following is the way to write in database.

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

constructor(
        private angularFireStore: AngularFirestore,
        
    ) {}


methods: {
  register: function(){
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.user_mail, this.user_password)
    .then(result=>{
      // this works
      console.log(result.user.uid)
      const userUid = result.user.uid;
      const data = {
          displayName: 'John',
       }

      createUserDoc(userUid, data);
    })
    .catch(error=>{
      console.log('something goes wrong on auth: ',error)
    })
  }
}

createUserDoc(userUid,userData){
   return this.angularFireStore.collection('users').doc(userUid).set(userData);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Since I'm not using angular, I have mimicked part of your script. Unfortunately, it still didn't change the results, so I'll try to find another way to do it. I've made some corrections to the questions in response to other people's comments, so if you have time, I hope you'll take a look at the questions again.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick. And if there is a problem when writing the user document (for example, a security rule that prevents it), you should see it in the catch block.

```
methods: {
  // ...
 
  register: function(){
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.user_mail, this.user_password)
    .then(result=>{
      // this works
      console.log(result.user.uid)

      // this does not work
      return db.collection('users').doc(result.user.uid).set({
        displayName: 'John',
      })
    })
    .catch(error=>{
      console.log('something goes wrong on auth: ',error)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. I changed to the code you suggested and tried to run the program, but it didn't work.
I tried to display the error with the catch syntax, but I didn't get any errors. I'm going to check another perspective, such as security rules. However, since I'm applying the lax security rules I added in the question box, I'm starting to wonder where in the world the problem lies. I'll check it out some more.